# Confused about pattern matching in Record constructions in Coq

Tags: coq

I've been using Coq for a very short time and I still bump into walls with some things. I've defined a set with a Record construction. Now I need to do some pattern matching to use it, but I'm having issues properly using it. First, these are my elements.

```
   Inductive element : Set :=
| empty  : element
.
.
.
| fun_m : element -> element -> element
| n_fun : nat -> element -> element
.
```

I pick the elements with certain characteristic to make a subset of them the next way:

```
Inductive esp_char : elements -> Prop :=
| esp1 : esp_char empty
| esp2 : forall (n : nat )(E : element), esp_char E -> esp_char (n_fun n E).

Record especial : Set := mk_esp{ E : element ; C : (esp_char E)}.
```

Now, I need to use definition and fix point on the 'especial' elements, just the two that I picked. I have read the documentation on Record and what I get is that I'd need to do something like this:

```
Fixpoint Size (E : especial): nat :=
match E with
|{|E := empty |}     => 0
|{|E := n_fun n E0|} => (Size E0) + 1
end.
```

Of course this tells me that I'm missing everything on the inductive part of elements so I add `{|E := _ |}=> 0`, or anything, just to make the induction full. Even doing this, I then find this problem:

```
|{|E := n_fun n E0|} => (Size E0) + 1

Error:
In environment
Size : especial -> nat
E : especial
f : element
i : esp_char f
n : nat
E0 : element
The term "E0" has type "element" while it is expected to have type "especial".
```

What I have been unable to do is fix that last thing, I have a lemma proving that if `n_fun n E0` is 'especial' then `E0` is especial, but I can't build it as so inside the Fixpoint. I also defined the size for "all elements" and then just picked the "especial" ones in a definition, but I want to be able to do direct pattern matching directly on the set "especial". Thank you for your input.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I also have a coercion to always send especial to elements.

EDIT: This is the approach I had before posting:

```
Fixpoint ElementSize (E : element): nat :=
match E with
| n_fun n E0 => (ElementSize E0) + 1
| _  => 0
 end.

Definition Size (E : especial) := ElementSize E.
```

Comment: Certainly things here don't line up and types are wrong (hint, try `About C`. I suggest you first define the size function on `element`, then compose it with the record accessor to get a size for `especial` (sic).

Comment: I did exactly what you suggest, seems like the most natural way, but I was demanded to do it with just one single Fixpoint, which is where I got stuck. I've edited to fix a couple of typos and add some details.

Comment: Oh well, that seems like a weird demand, see the answer as I cannot copy complete code here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have tried to do:

```
Lemma mk_especial_proof n E : esp_char (n_fun n E) -> esp_char E.
Proof. now intros U; inversion U. Qed.

Fixpoint Size (E : especial): nat := 
match E with
|{|E := empty              |} => 0
|{|E := n_fun n E0; C := P |} => (Size (mk_esp E0 (mk_especial_proof _ _ P))) + 1
|{|E := fun_m E1 E2        |} => 0
end.
```

However this will fail the termination check. I'm not familiar with how to overcome this problem with records. I'd definitively follow the approach I mentioned in the comments (using a fixpoint over the base datatype).

EDIT: Added single fixpoint solution.

```
Fixpoint size_e e :=
  match e with
  | empty       => 0
  | fun_m e1 e2 => 0
  | n_fun _   e => 1 + size_e e
  end.

Definition size_esp e := size_e (E e).
```

Comment: Thank you, I agree with the other approach, sadly I need this one (I don't understand the rationale behind it either). I've tried this and I get an error: Recursive call to Size has principal argument equal to
"{| E := E0; C := mk_especial_proof n E0 P0 |}" instead of
a subterm of "E". Do you know what this means or where I went wrong?

Comment: Just a note, the other approach allows you do to this task *with a single fixpoint*. The error message means that Coq can't figure out that `mk_esp ...` is a smaller term than the input term `E`.

Comment: I have edited my post with my original take on the solution, I have a Fixpoint and a definition, could you point me towards what to change to get Fixpoint to absorb the Definition? Thank you for your explanation too.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that's exactly what I'd done, but it is not being accepted as a valid solution. By now I think it's just out of stubbornness... If I see some other way I'll post it here

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly it is a bit weird... Maybe you could post the exact requirements?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help, this thing is driving me crazy as I don't see ways around it. Upon presenting the answer on my edit (and yours), I got as an answer, I quote: "this two parts construction is not a good way to do it. You can reuse your previous construction and assemble it in one single Fixpoint." I have asked many times what they mean by it and they just repeat a variation of that... Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Sara, I suggest you ask on the coq-club mailing list. Regarding the "is not a good way to do it part" I'm afraid I have to strongly disagree, as evidence in large proofs developments show. (Also, I wouldn't recommend to define `Small` in that particular way)

Answer (score 0):

I reduced your example to this, but you can easily go back to your definition.  We have a set, and a subset defined by an inductive predicate. Often one uses sigma types for this, with the notation `{b | Small b}`, but it is actually the same as the `Record` definition used in your example, so never mind :-).

```
Inductive Big : Set :=    (* a big set *)
| A
| B (b0 b1:Big)
| C (b: Big).

Inductive Small : Big -> Prop :=   (* a subset *)
| A' : Small A
| C' (b:Big) : Small b ->  Small (C b).

Record small := mk_small { b:Big ; P:Small b }.
```

Here is a solution.

```
Lemma Small_lemma: forall b, Small (C b) -> Small b.
Proof. intros b H; now inversion H. Qed.

Fixpoint size (b : Big) : Small b -> nat :=
    match b with
      | A => fun _ => 0
      | B _ _ => fun _ => 0
      | C b' => fun H => 1 + size b' (Small_lemma _ H)
    end.

Definition Size (s:small) : nat :=
  let (b,H) := s in size b H.
```

To be able to use the hypothesis `H` in the `match`-branches, it is sent into the branch as a function argument. Otherwise the destruction of b is not performed on the `H` term, and Coq can't prove that we do a structural recursion on `H`.